# Dealing with nested for Loops in Python to avoid duplicity

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, logic

In a scenario, we have one data Dictionary which has been traversed as the outer for loop and another data dictionary which will be traversed in the inner for loop.

```
dict1 = {ABC:India,BND:Argentina}
dict2 = {ABC:Namastey, BND : Hola}
```

Now, with the help of outer for loop, it will extract the values, India, Argentina etc like :

```
for key in dict1.keys():
         i_x_0=SubElement(samples, NODE_CONSTANTS['sample_node'])
         val = dict1[key]
         if key =='ABC':
                 append_str = "ASIA_"
                 a1 = append_str+val
                 if a1 not in i_x_0:
                     i_x_0.set('intentref', a1)
                     i_x_0.set('count', sample.count)
                     i_x_0.set("excluded", "true")
                     for x in BND.keys():
                          if x not in sample_node:
                           val1 = BND[x]
                           i_x_0.text = val1
         if key =='BND':
                 append_str = "CALA_"
                 a1 = append_str+val
                 if a1 not in i_x_0:
                     i_x_0.set('intentref', a1)
                     i_x_0.set('count', sample.count)
                     i_x_0.set("excluded", "true")
                     for x in BND.keys():
                          if x not in sample_node:
                           val1 = BND[x]
                           i_x_0.text = val1
```

If I keep the inner for loop like this, the result will only have Hola and not Namastey in i_x_0 .And if I keep the inner for loop just after the outer loop, it only execute one value per loop which is also not as expected. How can this be modified to get the exact result in i_x_0 , with getting Namastey, Hola etc being set correctly?

Comment: I have questions: What is `i_x_0`? How can this ever work: `if key =='India':`? Surely `key` is either `ABC` or `BND`?

Comment: i_x_0 can be considered as the sub element of the sample_node i have been using in which it will add like :  <sample intentref="ASIA_INDIA" count="1">Namastey</sample>

Comment: You need another `dict` which maps, eg. `ABC:"ASIA_"` etc.

Comment: The problem is not with setting the ASIA_ to India, problem arise when i am using the inner for loop to set the Namaste tag : i_x_0.text = val1 via this, somehow it is messed up , it is just adding the HOLA, instead of Namastey for all the IFs

Comment: But `i_x_0` must be the same each time round the loop, so surely the last one wins and overwrites any previous `i_x_0.text = val1`.

Comment: That's what is messed up, the override stuff, I wonder if you could help me how to overcome this override issues?

Comment: Ok, so what is `samples` and how do you add more elements. I assume you need to add multiple `<sample ...>` elements each with a different `intentref` attribute etc.

Comment: Issue resides in setting the i_x_0.text : ``` if temp_1==1:
           temp_1 = temp_1+1
           for key1,val1 in dict2 .items():
                val1 = dict2[key1]
                print("print key",val1)
                
                if val1 not in i_x_0:
                
                    i_x_0.text = ''.join(key1)                
           print("print val1",val1)     ```  In this one, instead of Namastey and Hola, it is only setting Hola overriding the Namastey part

Comment: But you still haven't said what `samples` is.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things you don't explain, but the basic problem is this line:

`i_x_0 = SubElement(samples, NODE_CONSTANTS['sample_node'])`

It keeps referring to the same `SubElement`.

I think you need this:

```py
i_x_0 = ET.Element('sample')
samples.append(i_x_0)
```

This will create a new element every time and you won't keep overwriting stuff.

Comment: Thanks but what i am looking for is to avoid the overriding in case of setting the i_x_0.text in this node, Also, samples as i mentioned it is being considered as the root/parent of this tree for which I am creating another sub-element and adding the content within,  and at last, my question remains intact that when i am trying to set the text via i_x_o : i_x_0.text = ''.join(key1) or i_x_0.text = val1, why it only adds Hola from dict2 and not Namastey

Comment: Where you have: `i_x_0.text = val1` this is an assignment which discards the previous value. Did you mean: `i_x_0.text += val1`?

Comment: i_x_0.text +=val1 / i_x_0.text = ''.join(val1), none of these work to avoid the overriding the previous value, have you encountered such with these two?

Comment: Ok, so: `i_x_0.text += ...` produces an error, but the code I am testing uses: `i_x_0 = ET.Element('sample');samples.append(i_x_0)` to produce a new `i_x_0` each time and then `i_x_0.text = ...` to write to each `text`. This produces an `XML` document with multiple `<sample ....> text </sample>` elements.

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm getting this all wrong. So what is: `BND.keys()`?

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet fixed the issue -

```
temp2 = 1    
        if temp==1:
            temp = temp+1
            print('dict2=',dict2 )
            for key in dict1.keys():
                    if key not in sample_node:
                        i_x_0=SubElement(samples, NODE_CONSTANTS['sample_node'])
                            val = dict1[key]
                            if val not in sample_node:
                              i_x_0.text = dict2[key]
```